# How to do bind next to a string in Angular?

Tags: angular, image, binding

I have two variables that form the link of an image, so I want to put them in the src tag:

```js
[src] = {{part1}}+"_"+{{part2}}
```

but it does not work for me. the script under "_" must go in the middle of the 2 parts since all the links have that underscore. How would it be the correct way? I have tried several ways and none works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do it `[src]='part1 + "_" + part2'` or `src="{{part1}}_{{part2}}"`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use template expressions you don't use double curly braces.

Template expressions looks:

```
[src]="part1 + ' ' + part2"
```

or interpolation with curly braces:

```
src="{{part1}} {{part2}}"
```

[Interpolation and Template Expressions in angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

Comment: thanks for answering. probe with this and do not load the image: src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i].id}}_{{inmuebles[i].fotos[0]}}", also try the other way and I get an error.

Comment: Can you describe what path is being created and what is expected? I do not understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`src = "{{part1 + '_' + part2}}"`

Evaluating your expression inside braces will give the desired result. This is because it accepts expression interpolation when using braces. Your value for `src` is a result so you do not need binding.